# How to change the content of the standard-modal?

Tags: vue.js

I am a Vue.js beginner... Supposing that the simplest and "standard" modal for Vue is https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html

But there are no ID or setter methodod to change the modal-body. I have many buttons and each one will show a different contengt (innerHTML) in the modal.. .But need only one Vue's modal object (not make sense do many if only changes title and content)... The content is not static is a string or inner HTML form other DOM object.

---

EDIT: as I discussing bellow, the key of the problem/solution and the question perhaps is "how to set a slot?"

The best is to see also [this question/answer about set string into innerHTML of the slot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49203123/287948).

---

```
<div id="app">

<button @click="showModal=true">Show Modal1</button>
<button @click="showModal=true">Show Modal2</button>


<modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">

    <!-- HOW TO CHANGE HERE??  DYNAMICALLY, ON FLY, 
       WITH PURE JAVASCRIPT

       WHEN click buttoom "Show Modal1" say "HELLO!"

       WHEN click buttoom "Show Modal2" say "BYE!"
        ... or get content from a web-service

    -->

    <h3 slot="header">custom header</h3>
  </modal>
</div>
```

Comment: can you rephrase the question? What do you want to do with the modal?

Comment: Hi @samayo, yes, I changed... And add the question in the comments of the piece of modal declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all `slot`s, so you can parameterized them.

E.g. in parent:

```
  <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
    <h3 slot="header">custom header</h3>
    <p slot="body">custom body</p>
    <p slot="footer">
      <button class="modal-default-button" @click="showModal = false">
        OK
      </button>
    </p>
  </modal>
```

This would change all three parts (header, body and footer).

[Updated JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/mwLbw11k/4631/).

## Creating multiple modals

To create multiple, you can have as many `<modal>`s as wanted, provided you create a "show" variable for each one (e.g. `showModal`):

```
<button id="show-modal" @click="showModalOne = true">Show Modal One</button>

<button id="show-modal" @click="showModalTwo = true">Show Modal Two</button>

<modal v-if="showModalOne" @close="showModalOne = false">
...
</modal>

<modal v-if="showModalTwo" @close="showModalTwo = false">
...
</modal>
```

And the data:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showModalOne: false,
    showModalTwo: false,
  }
})
```

[**Two modal JSFiddle here.**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/2qdh3x3v/10/)

Comment: Hi, thanks the clues!  Well... I need something "for dummies", not see how to set/change the slots.... I changed yout JSfiddle to 2 "showl modal" buttoms, https://jsfiddle.net/2qdh3x3v/   I need 2 different contents, "Hello!" for modal of buttom1 and "BYE" for buttom2.... How to do it?

Comment: Alrght! just a sec!

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it. I gave another suggestion on the answer.