# Easy way to set a slot with a string of a variable?

Tags: vue.js, slot

There are many `slot` examples but no clair and simple as I need... I need something like

```
 var x="Hello";
 $slot = x;
```

that is what I need...

In a concrete example: https://jsfiddle.net/2qdh3x3v/   
I need a *easy way* to set slot `header`  to "HELLO" when click "ShowModal1", and to "BYE!" when click "ShowModal2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable and change it by clicking on the desired button:

```
<button id="show-modal" @click="(header = 'HELLO') && (showModal = true)">
  Show Modal1
</button>
<button id="show-modal" @click="(header = 'BYE!') && (showModal = true)">
  Show Modal2
</button>
...
<h3 slot="header">{{header}}</h3>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6k9drL1t/1/

Comment: Hum... near there (!).  When use HTML not work, `header = 'HEL<big>LO</big>'` . There are no slot variable or *innerHTML* access for slot?

Comment: YES, seems the solution! I will try with my tests... Thanks