# Best way to a vue instance (app1) call another vue instance (app2)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Example:

```
    <div id="app1">  <button @click="etc...">run APP1</button> ..</div>

    <div id="app2">...   
      <button @click...>run APP1</button><!-- HERE! need a reference--> ...
      <button @click...>run APP2</button> 
    </div>
```

How to say to Vue in APP2 that **I need to call APP1**?

I need that both buttons "run APP1" do exactly the same thing. Supposing that, in the illustration, the first is working, and the second is a copy/paste... But the second will not work because is into app2.

Concrete case: see "GOOD1" and "GOOD2" buttons [at this code](https://jsfiddle.net/sLfoxak5/) similar to the used in the [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49202998/287948)...

Comment: What do you mean by "call APP1"?

Comment: Hi @acdcjunior, sorry, need better explanation, but the concrete example show the problem. Well...  suppose that the first buttom "run APP1" is working, so, I need that the second "run APP1" do exactly the same thing. If I only copy/paste (as in the illustration) it not works.

Comment: Is this it? https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/sLfoxak5/7/ If not, is it close? In this fiddle, `app1` is a custom component that emits a `go-modal` event, and the parent reacts to that event by getting the data the event sent and assigning it to the parent data.

Comment: Hi @acdcjunior, yes, seems that *emit* do the magic (where the guide-emit? [not at guide-event](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html))... But I dislike to redo all my simple div APP into a new template, I need only call, only the communication between two *Vue Instances* (app2 calling app1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every Vue instance implements an [events interface](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Instance-Methods-Events). This means that to communicate between two Vue instances (`app1` and `app2`) you can use [**Custom Events**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events).

So, in your example, before anything, give the first instance (that will emit events) a name so the other instance can reference it:

```
var app1 = new Vue({
  el: '#app1'
})
```

And emit events from it (this code is at `app1`'s template):

```
  <button @click="$emit('go-modal', {header: 'HEL<big>LO2</big>', showModal: true})">GOOD1</button>
  
  <button @click="$emit('go-modal', {header: 'BYE2', showModal: true})">GOOD2</button>
```

In the second instance (`app2`), listen to those events using `$on`:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app2',
  // ...
  mounted() {
    app1.$on('go-modal', this.handleApp1);
  },
  methods: {
    handleApp1(data) {
      this.header = data.header;
      this.showModal = data.showModal;
    }
  }
})
```

See [**demo JSFiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/sLfoxak5/15/).